# use multiple database in session store

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, express-session

i am using many database, in each database i have more than 40K users.

i have in each database a session table (for express-session)

now here's what i want to do:

to check if the user is authenticated: i recieve database name in user request (in the request header)

i want to pass database name in express-session

```
  store = new MSSQLStore(
              {
                user: env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
                password: env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
                server: env.DATABASE_HOST,
                database: req.headers.nombase, // get database name from request
                autoRemove: true
              },
```

the problem is i didn't know how to access and pass database name (from the request) to session middleware

here is what i did but it didn't work:

```
app.use( function(req,res,next){
        store = new MSSQLStore(
          {
            user: env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
            password: env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            server: env.DATABASE_HOST,
            database: req.headers.nombase, // get database name from request
            autoRemove: true
          },
          {
            ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          }
        );
      req.app.use(session(
        {
          secret: env.SESSION_SECRET,
          resave: false,
          saveUninitialized: false,
          name: env.SESSION_NAME,
          store: store,
          cookie: {
            path: "/",
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
          }
        }))
        next();
      }
    )
```

want to check the existence of the session based on the user's request (because each user group is linked to a specific database)

So, when the user sends a request, I want to check the session in the database which it is linked to

Comment: can you be more specific what exact solution do you want, i don't think its a programming question but a rather architectural question, can you explain it further so i can make your question better?

Comment: i want to check database name in each request and use it (database name) in session store
i am using many databases and i want to have sessions table in each database.

Comment: why not use an id and store it in session and against that ID check which database to connect to, you can use redis for this.. it will be a lot safer to keep your database information to yourself

Comment: sorry,  i didn't understand your solution. for what i am gone use the ID PS:  i recieve just database reference from the client. the actual database name is encrypted